# How can I make Word 2010 use a single bracket for multiple linked citations?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Currently, when I add a citation in my Word document I get something like:

•   Edge detection [45] [46] [47]

I'd like this to be:

•   Edge detection [45, 46, 47]

without converting the citation to static text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your cursor before the last bracket when inserting the citation, it should insert it as separated by a semicolon.